# WebRequests in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome

I'm struggling with a Chrome extension.

I have an Authorization header value which I want to append to a response to the next Authorization request, so I found the event `onAuthRequired` (which is said to "Fire when a request requires authentication of the user."), and tried adding a listener to it; unsuccessfully. By looking at this example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
                details.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
    [ "blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

in which the User-Agent header is removed, I assume I can append my header by the same principle, using `details.requestHeaders = theHeader;` or similar.

I am obviously not the King of JavaScript, so I have to turn to you, the mighty Internet. It would be awesome to be presented some examples of modifying request headers, as it seems there aren't that many around.. An example using `onAuthRequired` is of course what I want the most :).

Note: I have been investigating `XMLHttpRequest`, but I need to establish its state inside the browser context. Authenticating once using `XMLHttpRequest` yields only one authorized GET, but supplying the browser with the Authorization header link the authorization with the browser context.